# Distribute a payment value through monthly period

Tags: php, arrays

Imagine a scenario where monthly rent is 100,000 which is payable at the end of each month.
A tenant then decides to make a payment 350,000 to cater for the current month and those ahead. How do I distribute this amount since I can obviously see here that this amount caters for 3 months and a half month? 
Here is what I was trying in PHP but I just can't get the last 50,000 to appear.

```
$rent       = 100000; // rent amount
$amountPaid = 350000; // amount paid by tenant

$length     = $amountPaid/$rent; // number of months paid for

for ($c = 1; $c <= $length; $c++) 
{
    $foreachMonth = $rent;
    assignRentFunction($c, $foreachMonth);
}

function assignRentFunction($count, $amt)
{
    echo "Month ".$count.': '.$amt."<br>";
}
```

Comment: You should try to formulate your question in a way that doesn't involve all your business logic (which we don't know a lot about). Instead you could formulate it as: I have input X and my result should be an array in the form [100000, 100000, 100000] or something similar. I atleast don't understand what you are asking :/.

Comment: `$length == 3.5` ??????

Comment: `$months = floor($amountPaid / $rent); $rest = $amountPaid % $rent`

Comment: @Xatenev sorry about that. I couldn't figure out a way to explain it much better.

Comment: @RomanHocke can you please provide a little explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Steps:**

1) Get total months with `ceil()` function.

2) It will return 4 months. 3 months fully paid and one month paid only 50000.

3) Now, for each loop will add 10000 to total rent paid.

4) if this surpasses the amount paid, get mod which is 50000

```
$rent       = 100000; // rent amount
$amountPaid = 350000; // amount paid by tenant
$length     = ceil($amountPaid/$rent); // number of months paid for
$totalRent = 0;
for ($c = 1; $c <= $length; $c++) {
    $totalRent += $rent;
    $foreachMonth = $rent;
    if ($amountPaid < $totalRent) { // Here is the logic, if amount exceeds, use the remaining amount.
        $foreachMonth = $amountPaid % $rent;
    }    
    assignRentFunction($c, $foreachMonth);
}
function assignRentFunction($count, $amt) {
    echo "Month ".$count.': '.$amt."<br>";
}

**Output:**

Month 1: 100000
Month 2: 100000
Month 3: 100000
Month 4: 50000
```

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful responses. I should a little more reading on this ceil and floor function since it seems to be help a lot with floats.  @Pupil , your solution nailed it.

Comment: @RupinyEric, it is really an amazing feeling when a solution with my little knowledge helps somebody. Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 5):

Since there seems to be a few ways to slice this, I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring also:

```
for($c = 1; $c<=ceil($amountPaid/$rent); $c++){
    assignRentFunction($c, $rent - max(($c * $rent - $amountPaid),0));
}
```

And now the commented version:

```
for($month = 1; $month<=ceil($amountPaid/$rent); $month++){
    //For each month there is money for rent (using ceil() to account for fractions)

    assignRentFunction(
        $month,
        // The number of the month

        $rent
        //Show the rent ($rent)

        -
        //Deduct

        max(($month * $rent - $amountPaid),0)
        //Any difference if the whole rent for that month hasn't been paid

        /**
         * This relies on a little hack with the max() function:
         * max($var,0) will return 0 if $var is less than 0.
         * So we check to see if the sum of rent up to that month ($month * $rent)
         * is greater than what was paid ($month * $rent) - $amountPaid.
         * If it isn't because it's wrapped in the max,
         * the net (negative) number will just be shown as nill.
         * If it is, the net positive number will be subtracted
         * from the month's rent.
         **/
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$rent= 100000; // rent amount
$amountPaid= 350000; // amount paid by tenant
$length= $amountPaid/$rent; // number of months paid for
for ($c = 1; $c <= ceil($length); $c++) 
{
    $foreachMonth = 100000;
    if($amountPaid>$rent)
    {
        $rent=$rent;
        $amountPaid=$amountPaid-$rent;
    }
    else
    {
        $rent=$rent-$amountPaid;
    }
    assignRentFunction($c, $rent);
}

function assignRentFunction($count, $amt)
{

    echo "Month ".$count.': '.$amt."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your loop part to

```
for ($c = 1; $c <= $length; $c++) { 
  $foreachMonth = $rent;
  assignRentFunction($c, $foreachMonth);
}
$fractionalMonth = $length - intval($length);
if ($fractionalMonth)
  assignRentFunction($c, $foreachMonth * $fractionalMonth);
```

Your error was since you're always incrementing `$c` by one, you wasn't able to get the fractional part for the last month

Answer (score 4):

You can solve your problem like this,

```
$rent       = 100000; // rent amount
$amountPaid = 350000; // amount paid by tenant
$length     = ceil($amountPaid / $rent); // number of months paid for
$temp1      = $amountPaid;
for ($c = 1; $c <= $length; $c++) {
    if($temp1 < $rent){ // assigning left amount to rent if less than amount left
        $rent = $temp1;
    }
    if($temp1 > $rent){ // checking if amount left is still more than per month rent then minus that rent from pending paid amount
        $temp1 = $temp1 - $rent;
    }
    assignRentFunction($c, $rent);
}
function assignRentFunction($count, $amt)
{
    echo "Month " . $count . ': ' . $amt . "<br>";
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec3770912c8554eba8053d3dbc99a93a16fc95ba).